# How to get a opportunity owner name based on opportunity id

Tags: apex, soql, opportunity

Hi i am new to salesforce development i got a requirement like based on the opportunity owner i have to update a custom field in opportunity page.I create a after trigger in opportunity.we don't have to access opportunity owner directly so i write soql query to get opportunity owner based on opportunity id.But i don't have knowledge on test classes.can anyone share how to write a test class for this code

for reference i am posting my code.

```
 trigger UpdateTeamOnOpp on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
/** @var ownerMap - map of Owner Ids to their matching Owner Record */
Map<Id,User> ownerMap;
/** @var oppOwnerIds - set of Opportunity Owner Ids from the inserted / updated records */
Set<Id> oppOwnerIds = new Set<Id>();
/** @var nameOfOwner - will hold the name of the Oppturnity Owner */
String nameOfOwner;
public String owners,ownerstemp;
owners = Label.Owners;
List<String> parts = owners.split(',');
ownerstemp = Label.owners_ver_2;
List<String> partstemp = ownerstemp.split(',');

for(Opportunity opps : trigger.new){ // loop through all updated/inserted opps
    oppOwnerIds.add(opps.OwnerId); // add the owner id to the set of owner ids
    System.debug('Opportunity Id'+opps.OwnerId); 
} 

ownerMap = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id IN :oppOwnerIds]);

for(Opportunity opps : trigger.new){ // loop through the updated/inserted opps again
    nameOfOwner = ownerMap.get(opps.OwnerId).Name; // use the opportunity owner id to grab the record from the map
    for(String s:parts) {
    if(s.equals( nameOfOwner)) { 
        opps.light_weight__Team_name__c='Avengers';
        }
    }
    for(String s:partstemp) {
    if(s.equals( nameOfOwner)) { 
        opps.light_weight__Team_name__c='Captain America';
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change your query to `Select Owner.Name From Opportunity Where Id = :names`

Comment: Also, just as a side note. Don't perform SOQL queries inside of a trigger. It is considered bad practice. Also some semantic meaning on your variable names would be nicer to read.

Comment: i had changed also but i got same error it's only alias right there is no problem with that right @JesseMilburn

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestion for variable names it just for testing i will definitely follow naming conventions @JesseMilburn

Comment: So what is your debug showing right below your query? without the `.size()`

Comment: and you are correct about the alias, I just hardly every use them with SOQL and messed something up when I copied your query into my workbench.

Comment: Hey i think you are new to development right because i had already go through the debug logs then only i know the list is empty @Jesse Milburn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query has `WHERE o.Id=:'names'` try removing the single quotes since it is a variable name and not a string as noted in the comments.
Also noted in the comments, you do not want to have a query being performed inside a for loop.
You also are only checking the first result of the trigger so if mutliple records were updated simultaneously with different owners this will cause you some issues.
I would suggest something like:
Create a set of user ids;
Create a map from the result of query on User of Ids to User object include the name;
Loop through the trigger.new list and use the owner id to access the user record from the map to check the name.

```
trigger UpdateTeamOnOpp on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    /** @var ownerMap - map of Owner Ids to their matching Owner Record */
    Map<Id,User> ownerMap;
    /** @var oppOwnerIds - set of Opportunity Owner Ids from the inserted / updated records */
    Set<Id> oppOwnerIds = new Set<Id>();
    /** @var nameOfOwner - will hold the name of the Oppturnity Owner */
    String nameOfOwner;

    for(Opportunity opps : trigger.new){ // loop through all updated/inserted opps
        oppOwnerIds.add(opps.OwnerId); // add the owner id to the set of owner ids
        System.debug('Opportunity Id'+opps.OwnerId); 
    } 

    ownerMap = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id IN :oppOwnerIds]);

    for(Opportunity opps : trigger.new){ // loop through the updated/inserted opps again
        nameOfOwner = ownerMap.get(opps.OwnerId).Name; // use the opportunity owner id to grab the record from the map
        if (nameOfOwner == 'Test Bennett') { // check to see if owner name meets the test team criteria
            opps.Team_Name__c = 'Test'; // if it does then set the Team to Test
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative you could use Process Builder:
[image: process builder working example]

Comment: Hey thanks i know it doesn't handle bulk records.I'm in testing so this requirement is in testing so i want to know the solution.To change it to bulk is not a problem right.After completed the testing every time i had created a class to put all my code.And call this from a trigger.But what you said is everything right because these are the best practices right @Jenny B

Comment: Hey you said actually i forgot to remove single quotes while working with hard-coded opportunity id it works fine but i forgot to remove it takes as a value..@Jenny B

Comment: Hey @Jenny B i got another problem that is System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Comment: @Pavantej since you are doing after insert and update you will have to create a list of updates and do a separate dml. before will allow you to update the record directly.

Comment: Hey even i am try to go to process builder for this requirement but i thought it leads to two problems they are in my requirement i want to update a field based on opportunity owner like some users are assigned with a group name. 1.But if i deactivated a user or i want to add any user  from my org i can't edit process builder i have to clone the process and edit that. @Jenny B

Comment: @Pavantej I do not see the listed issues, but I just tested this in my dev org and it worked fine.

Comment: ya we can't edit process created from process builder.But now i had faced with this exception System.FinalException: Record is read-only @Jenny B

Comment: @Pavantej - you might be having recursion issues since you are updating after an insert update it is probably rerunning. Since you have resolved the query issue, you might be better off starting a new question with your new problem and updated code.

Comment: hi your code works fine and i had just added the custom labels to the apex class and split the data in the label based on the comma.It works fine but i don't had an idea to create test class means i have to create a dummy and change that opportunity like that can you please help with test code i just modified my question with updated apex class. @Jenny B

Comment: @Pavantej - glad to hear you got it working, I would suggest writing down the steps to test this in the UI and then creating the test data and step through those steps in the test class. Use asserts to assert the expected outcome. If you get stuck or have issues please open a new question with what your class and test class have and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: ok sure you save a lot of time man thanks for sharing knowledge....       @Jenny B

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with after triggers so i can't do any database commit and if i'm try to go with before insert i'm querying records based opportunity id's so it cant possible to get opportunity id in before insert triggers.so i had change the soql query opportunity id to ownerid it resolves my problem.

here is the code

```
trigger OwnerMapping on Opportunity (after insert,after update)  
{
 public String name;
 public string[] lists;
 public String nameinlist;
 List<opportunity> oppsowner= new List<opportunity> ();
 public Id details;
      for(opportunity opps:trigger.new) 
        {
           details = opps.OwnerId;
           System.debug('Opportunity Id'+details);
           nameinlist=namesList(details);
            i f(nameinlist.equals('test user')) 
            {
              opps.light_weight__Team_name__c='test';
            }
         }

      public String namesList(Id names) 
         {
            oppsowner=[Select Owner.Name From Opportunity where OwnerId=:names];
            System.debug('List size '+oppsowner.size());
            name=oppsowner.get(0).Owner.Name;
            return name;
         } 
 }
```

Comment: Didn't catch that you had used opps.Id,  glad you figured it out!

Comment: updated my answer with a bulkified example of what you are doing.